# (Bucket Not Deleted) Amazon S3 error- A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses, bucket

Why I got this error when I try to create a bucket in amazon S3? My buck still exists and is not deleted but I'm just trying to attach SNS topic to my bucket

[Bucket error pictured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN65i.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing similar issues. There was an AWS service interruption for S3 in us-east-1.

https://status.aws.amazon.com/

Everything looks OK on my end now.